# how to get value from custom child view in parent view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Hi guys I am integrating an app with dynamic child `View` in a parent `View`.

My code to adding child `View` in parent view XML file.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/add_view"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is my code for add child view in `Activity`.

```
for (int i = 0;i < BloodInstance.getInstance().tempBloodResultDetails.size();i++){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.child_view, null);
            BloodResultDetails details = BloodInstance.getInstance().tempBloodResultDetails.get(i);
            resultName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.child_name);
            resultRange = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.child_range);
            resultGetRange = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.child_get_range);

            resultName.setText(details.getName());
            resultRange.setText("Normal Range "+details.getMinRange()+" to "+details.getMaxRange()+" "+details.getUnit());

            addLayout.addView(view);
        }
```

Here is my child `View` XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="#e1e1e1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/child_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:typeface="serif"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/child_range"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:text="Normal Range"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/child_get_range"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Your Range"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/box"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I have use this code to save the values.

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i = 0;i < BloodInstance.getInstance().tempBloodResultDetails.size();i++){
                    String result = resultGetRange.getText().toString();
                    Log.e("Result",result);
                    resultUserRange.add(result);
                }
            }
        });
```

How to get value from `EditText` for each child `View`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give an ID to the `View`:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.child_view, null);
int id = View.generateViewId();
view.setId(id);
```

After that you could do something like this to get the text from your `EditText`:

```
View parent = findViewById(id);
EditText child = (EditText) parent.findViewById(R.id.child_get_range);
String text = child.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the for-loop for  addLayout(parent view) to get the child view, like.

```
for(int ij=0;ij<addLayout.getChildCount();ij++)
{
    //get user view here
}
```

then set id for views in add views like that  `view.setId(id);`